# Scala GC out of memory issue

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection

I am getting the following exception:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

with this stack trace:

```
at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.updated0(HashSet.scala:230)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.$plus(HashSet.scala:56)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.$plus(HashSet.scala:33)
at scala.collection.SetLike$$anonfun$$plus$plus$1.apply(SetLike.scala:128)
at scala.collection.SetLike$$anonfun$$plus$plus$1.apply(SetLike.scala:128)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:105)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:138)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:105)
at scala.collection.SetLike$class.$plus$plus(SetLike.scala:128)
at scala.collection.AbstractSet.$plus$plus(Set.scala:47)
```

I'll sketch my code that calls `++` here:

```
  val features = Array[(String, Double)]() ++
  featuresExtractor.map {
    case (// ...) =>
        (featureNameString, featureValueDouble)
      }
    case (// ...) =>
      Option(...)
      match {
        case None =>
          terms.map { term: String => (term, 0.0d) }
        case Some(...) =>
          terms.map { term: String =>                
            val value: Option[Double] = ...
            (featureName, value.getOrElse(0.0d)
          }
      }
  }.reduce(_ ++ _)
```

This code basically iterates over `featuresExtractor` (a `Map`) to produce an `Array[(String, Double)]`.

My question is: is the excessive creation of small objects that GC spends a lot of time trying to recover due to me (I am just creating many of those), or is this a Scala data structure issue?

And a follow up would be: should I give up on `reduce` here and try another approach to work around that problem?

Comment: `reduce` is creating a new `immutable.HashSet` from each instance being passed to it for concatenation `_ ++ _`. It's you.

Comment: Thanks Yuval - I'm modifying to make those sets become arrays before going to reduce. I actually get the sets from a library call, but I can convert them to arrays in my code before throwing them at reduce.

Comment: Perhaps instead of `reduce`, use `foldLeft` with a mutable seed which can accumulate all the data and save you all these allocations.

Comment: I like the suggestion, I will give it a try. Thanks again!

Comment: "My question is: is the excessive creation of small objects that GC spends a lot of time trying to recover due to me ".  Creating too many objects doesn't  in itself cause out of memory. It might cause a lot of garbage collections. Your problem is not that you are creating too many, it's that too many are still "alive" and can't be collected.